# How to use XMLHttpRequest() to store a JSON in a Laravel database?

Tags: php, json, laravel, post, surveyjs

My current error is that I'm seemingly not getting information to my controller, Auth::user doesn't seem to work, and if there is a way to print information in the controller? No dump, dd, var_dump, etc. seems to show me anything.

This is my JavaScript inside my script tags in my blade. (Taken from Surveyjs.io)

```
var survey = new Survey.Model(this.surveyJSON, surveyContainer);
                survey.onComplete.add(function (sender, options) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/api/survey");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(sender.data));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(sender.data));
```

I then have my Route::post in web.php. I want my data to be sent to retrieval() in CreateController.

```
Route::post('/api/survey', [\App\Http\Controllers\CreateController::class,'retrieval'])->name('survey-questions');
```

In my CreateController.php I am wanting to store the incoming json with the current user's id.

```
Survey::create(['answers' => response()->json($request->all()), 'author_id' => Auth::user()]);
```

Comment: "No dump, dd, var_dump, etc. seems to show me anything." — Where are you looking for the output?

Comment: I was looking for the JSON's info to confirm that it made it to the controller. However, nothing would print.

Comment: Yes but **where** are you looking for that?

Comment: In the request that I get from the route. So I looked everywhere online to find the right methods to pull the info from the request. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I'm expecting you to say something like "In the PHP log files" or "In some specific part of the browser UI"

Comment: I guess I don't know where those are. I guess if my controller isn't linked to a webpage then I don't quite know where to look for an output...

Comment: Well, for AJAX requests a good place to look is in the Network tool (part of the browser's Developer Tools). There you can see each request and you can click into them to see exactly what data was sent and received for each one.

Answer (score 1):

## Figured it Out!

I found the answer thanks to Quentin. I leared more about laravel.log and how to print messages there using Log::info($data).

I changed Auth::user() to Auth::user->id and changed:

```
Survey::create(['answers' => response()->json($request->all()), 'author_id' => Auth::user()]);
```

to

```
Survey::create(['answers' => json_encode($data), 'author_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
```

Thanks everybody for your comments!